# How to remove all same data from a list<String> exept the last ? with flutter

Tags: flutter

I search to remove all same data from a list exept the last same

I have an input list like that :

```
[2020-11-04,note0:blabla, ... data_random ... 2020-11-04,note0:srgg, ... data_random ... ,2020-11-15,note0:test, ... data_random ... , 2020-11-15,note0:test1, ... data_random ... , 2020-11-15,note0:test2, ... data_random ... , 2020-11-15,note0:test3]
```

I search to keep only the last `2020-11-15,note0:test3`

and remove `2020-11-04,note0:blabla, 2020-11-04,note0:srgg, 2020-11-15,note0:test, 2020-11-15,note0:test1, 2020-11-15,note0:test2`

thank you

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicate elements or all elements except the last one?

Comment: remove all duplicate elements except the last one. only the key ,note0: is fixe. I need to remove all duplicate key ,note0 who have the same date and remove also his data. Except the last one. Date depend of user, so it's random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since they are common in "2020-11-15,note0:" you can use a reverse for loop like this and check if they contain this: "2020-11-15,note0:"

```
List keepTheLast() {
List input = [
  "2020-11-15,note0:test",
  "... data_random ... ",
  "2020-11-15,note0:test1",
  "... data_random ...",
  "2020-11-15,note0:test2",
  "... data_random ... ",
  "2020-11-15,note0:test3"
];
bool found = false;
for (int i = input.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  if (input[i].contains("2020-11-15,note0:"))
    found ? input.removeAt(i) : found = true;
print(input.toString());
return input;}
```

and the res would be:

```
 [... data_random ... , ... data_random ..., ... data_random ... , 2020-11-15,note0:test3]
```

Comment: Thank you for this example, but I forget to specify that the date is variable, I can't determine before a static date, it's random :(

Comment: I adapte with regex and loop for and It work, it's certainly ugly but work ^^ thank you for you example